# React material-ui grid : is it possible to add breakpoints?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

since I changed breakpoints values to the theme:

```
breakpoints: {
      values: {
        xs: 0,
        sm: 568,
        md: 760,
        lg: 960,
        xl: 1200,
      },
```

i'd like to add an `xxl:1400` breakpoint to use like so:

```
<Grid item xxl="4" md="6" xs="12">
```

Is it possible?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is not fully supported in v4, but it is partially supported and you can create a custom Grid component to fully support it. If you add additional breakpoint keys, Material-UI will [generate the appropriate CSS classes](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/v4.4.0/packages/material-ui/src/Grid/Grid.js#L197) for all of them, but it will **not** look for the `xxl` prop and therefore will not apply the appropriate class automatically ([here](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/v4.4.0/packages/material-ui/src/Grid/Grid.js#L240) is where it checks for the standard breakpoint props).

Below is a working v4 example with a `GridWithXXL` component that takes care of applying the appropriate `xxl` CSS class.

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import { createMuiTheme, MuiThemeProvider } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import Grid from "@material-ui/core/Grid";

const theme = createMuiTheme({
  breakpoints: {
    keys: ["xs", "sm", "md", "lg", "xl", "xxl"],
    values: { xs: 0, sm: 568, md: 760, lg: 960, xl: 1200, xxl: 1400 }
  }
});
const GridWithXXL = ({ xxl, ...other }) => {
  const xxlClass = `MuiGrid-grid-xxl-${xxl}`;
  return <Grid className={xxlClass} {...other} />;
};
function App() {
  return (
    <MuiThemeProvider theme={theme}>
      <Grid container>
        {[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12].map(item => {
          return (
            <GridWithXXL
              key={item}
              item
              xs={12}
              sm={6}
              md={4}
              lg={3}
              xl={2}
              xxl={1}
            >
              Item {item}
            </GridWithXXL>
          );
        })}
      </Grid>
    </MuiThemeProvider>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

[image: Edit custom Grid breakpoint keys]

In v5, custom breakpoints are fully supported out of the box by `Grid`. Here's an equivalent v5 example:

```
import React from "react";
import { createRoot } from "react-dom/client";

import { createTheme, ThemeProvider } from "@mui/material/styles";
import Grid from "@mui/material/Grid";

const theme = createTheme({
  breakpoints: {
    keys: ["xs", "sm", "md", "lg", "xl", "xxl"],
    values: { xs: 0, sm: 568, md: 760, lg: 960, xl: 1200, xxl: 1400 }
  }
});
function App() {
  return (
    <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
      <Grid container>
        {[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12].map((item) => {
          return (
            <Grid key={item} item xs={12} sm={6} md={4} lg={3} xl={2} xxl={1}>
              Item {item}
            </Grid>
          );
        })}
      </Grid>
    </ThemeProvider>
  );
}

const root = createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));
root.render(<App />);
```

[image: Edit custom Grid breakpoint keys]

Comment: Thanks! It's working for the  grid (had to upgrade to mui 4.40). But method isWidthUp is not working.  xxl  won't be understand as above xl.

Comment: Instead of `isWidthUp` you should use [useMediaQuery](https://material-ui.com/components/use-media-query/#using-material-uis-breakpoint-helpers) which will work with the custom breakpoint key.

Comment: This approach doesn't work with v3 because the "Mui" class names were generated with unpredictable names (e.g. "jss<number>" in production mode, and with a somewhat unpredictable index on the end in development mode such as "MuiGrid-grid-xxl-1-9"). In v4 the "Mui" class names stay consistent so long as you aren't using nested themes. Within a nested theme, an index will be tacked on to the end (same as v3 development mode) to distinguish it from the same class in the top-level theme.

Comment: can't you just wrap it in the custom provider?, why is anything else necessary

Comment: @SeanMC This is a pretty old question/answer. In MUI v5, the custom Grid component is not necessary.

Comment: @RyanCogswell then whats the new method?

Comment: @SeanMC I've added a v5 example to clarify.